# Recursion: Terminating all instances upon reaching end condition

Tags: java, selenium, recursion, webdriver

I have a list of webElements that I need to loop through and click on each one, however because each click refreshes the page I get a StaleElementReferenceException. Each element looks like this:

```
<img src="images/english/edit.gif" border="0" height="24" width="47">
```

So I use a recursive method to click on each webElement then pass on the index to the next instance and refreshing the list:

```
public int enterDescription(int place)
{
    List descriptions = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(img[src='images/english/edit.gif']));
```

`for (int index = 0; index < descriptions.size(); index++) 
           {
               index = place;
               if(place==descriptions.size()) 
               {
                   return place;
               } 
               else
               {
                   descriptions.get(index).click();
                   enterDescription(place++);
               }
           }
        return place;   }`

This works initially up until the finishing condition when the method crashes, upon reaching the end condition I need to terminate all instances at once. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need recursion for this? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No its not, If there is another way the please advise.

Comment: You can use a simple loop for this I guess.

Comment: I have tried that before it throws a StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: Recursion is not going to help with that. I think that you have to check your elements whether they are stale or not.

Comment: I have solve the problem it is the loop, i have removed it and it has sloved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need recursion to do this.  You would only need to refresh your descriptions at the beginning of each pass through the for statement.  Something like this:

```
    public void enterDescription() {
        int numberOfImages = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(img[src='images/english/edit.gif'])).size();

    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++) {
        List<WebElement> descriptions = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(img[src='images/english/edit.gif']));
        descriptions.get(index).click();
        // Test something
        // Do something to return to initial page
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ignoring the recursion stuff you you achieve your wish for termination with this structure

```
public interface Terminatable {
    void terminate();
}

public class Terminator {
    private LinkedList<Terminatable> terminatables = new LinkedList<Terminatable>();

    public void register(Terminatable terminatable) {
        terminatables.offer(terminatable);
    }

    public void unregister(Terminatable terminatable) {
        terminatables.remove(terminatable);
    }

    public void terminate() {
        Terminatable terminatable = terminatables.poll();

        while(terminatable != null) {
            terminatable.terminate();
            terminatable = terminatables.poll();
        }
    }
}

public class Worker implements terminatable {
    private Terminator terminator;

    public Worker(Terminator terminator) {
        this.terminator = terminator;
        terminator.register(this);
    }

    public void terminate() {
        // do your termination stuff here
    }

    [...]

    public void work() {
        // do your work and start termination when you are finished
        terminator.terminate();
    }
}
```

rememeber to unregister your Workers if you no longer need them!